# »Beachten Sie, dass das Dokument in Wahrheit zwei Dokumente ist/sind.«

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich muss jemanden eine pdf-Datei schicken, die die Scans von zwei längeren Ausdrucken mit Unterschriften mit 9 und 61 Seiten enthält. Um dem Empfänger klar zu machen, dass in dem pdf-Dokument zwei Dokumente stecken, würde ich ihm im Begleit-E-Mail gerne Folgendes schreiben:

> Bitte beachten Sie, dass das pdf-Dokument in Wahrheit zwei Dokumente **ist.**

Ich bin mir aber unsicher, ob das Verb *sein* hier richtig im Singular steht, oder ob es nicht *»sind«* heißen müsste:

> Bitte beachten Sie, dass das pdf-Dokument in Wahrheit zwei Dokumente **sind.**

Ich bin mir unsicher, weil mir beide Versionen falsch vorkommen.

In einem Hauptsatz würde das ja so aussehen:

> Das pdf-Dokument **ist** in Wahrheit zwei Dokumente.

Hier bin ich mir recht sicher, dass das falsch wäre:

> <del>*Das pdf-Dokument **sind** in Wahrheit zwei Dokumente.*</del>

Hat hier die Platzierung in einem Nebensatz eine Auswirkung auf die Wahl des Numerus des Verbs?

---

**Nachtrag (Reaktion auf Kommentare):**

Ich habe mein Anliegen offenbar nicht klar genug zum Ausdruck gebracht:

Ich bin durchaus in der Lage, anstelle des genannten Satzes auch andere Formulierungen zu finden. Es geht mir hier in dieser Frage nicht darum, den geschilderten Sachverhalt möglichst elegant in Worte zu kleiden. Das kann ich durchaus auch ohne Unterstützung.

Es geht mir stattdessen um diese Frage: Muss in dem Satz, der im Titel der Frage steht, das letzte Wort im Singular oder im Plural stehen?

---

**Nachtrag 2:**

Daran wird vermutlich niemand etwas auszusetzen haben:

> a) Zwei Liebende sind ein Paar.

Sowohl »zwei Liebende« als auch »ein Paar« liegen im Nominativ vor. Beide kommen daher als Subjekt in Frage. Die jeweils andere Wortgruppe ist dann ein Nominativobjekt, ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ, ein Prädikatsnomen oder ein Subjektsprädikativ (alle vier Namen bezeichnen denselben grammatischen Sachverhalt).

Im Deutschen darf man aber die Reihenfolge von Satzgliedern verändern (unter gewissen Voraussetzungen, die in Sätzen der Form »X Verb Y« aber immer erfüllt sind, solange das Verb in der Mitte bleibt):

> Der Jäger erschießt den Hasen. ⟷ Den Hasen erschießt der Jäger.
>   Die Gemeinde gedenkt der Gefallenen. ⟷ Der Gefallenen gedenkt die Gemeinde.
>   Der Hut gehört dem Kellner. ⟷ Dem Kellner gehört der Hut.
>   Der Zug fährt schnell. ⟷ Schnell fährt der Zug.
>   Ein Buch liegt auf dem Tisch. ⟷ Auf dem Tisch liegt ein Buch.

Das geht auch mit den Liebenden:

> b) Ein Paar sind zwei Liebende.

Allerdings kann man in diesem Fall auch »ein Paar« als Subjekt auffassen, was es notwendig macht, den Numerus des Verbs an dieses Subjekt anzupassen:

> c) Ein Paar ist zwei Liebende.

Aber auch hier darf man vertauschen:

> d) Zwei Liebende ist ein Paar.

Meine Frage lautet nun: Welche der vier Sätze (a, b, c und d) sind richtig? Welche sind falsch?

Comment: Unabhängig von der Ausgangsfrage: Warum nicht einfach "Bitte beachten Sie, dass die pdf-Datei zwei unterschiedliche Dokumente enthält."?

Comment: Erstens: Warum sollten in einem Hauptsatz andere Regeln gelten als in einem Nebensatz?

Comment: Zweitens: Ich hätte im Hauptsatz "Das Dokument ist/sind zwei Dokumente." Plural (also "sind") als richtig und Singular als falsch empfunden.

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt klingt es nicht nur sprachlich seltsam, es ergibt für mich auch inhaltlich nicht viel Sinn. Ich würde den Vorschlag von @mtwde unterstützen. (P.S.: "Ich bin zwei Öltanks"?)

Comment: Die doppelte Verwendung von Dokument würde ich vermeiden, etwa durch `dass in der PDF-Datei 2 Dokumente stecken.` oder `dass das PDF zwei Dokumente enthält`.

Comment: @mtwde: Ich weiß schon, dass man das Problem *vermeiden* kann, indem man eine andere Formulierung wählt. Ich habe die Frage hier aber gestellt weil es dieses Problem *gibt* und ich es gerne *lösen* würde.

Comment: @userunknown: Meine Antwort an mtwde gilt auch hier: Ich bin nicht auf der Suche nach einer anderen Formulierung (das schaffe ich durchaus ohne Hilfe). Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer Antwort auf die gestellte Frage.

Comment: Auch die Aussage "Das pdf-Dokument ist in Wahrheit zwei Dokumente" halte ich für nicht richtig. Meiner Meinung gibt es auf die Frage keine richtige Antwort, da die Formulierung an sich falsch ist. Man sagt weder "eins ist zwei" noch "eins sind zwei". Einfach weil eins und zwei verschieden sind :-)

Comment: @puck: Du irrst. Siehe Nachtrag 2 (1 Paar = 2 Liebende).

Comment: Von den vier Sätzen würde ich sagen a und b sind richtig. 1 Paar = 2 Liebende stimmt genauso wie 1 Dutzend = 12 Stück oder 1 Woche = 7 Tage. Das sind alles verschiedene Wörter, da geht so etwas. Beim selben Wort kann man meiner Meinung nicht die verschiedene Anzahl gleichsetzen. Das hat nichts mit der Umstellung von Wörtern in einem Satz zu tun. 1 Dokument nicht gleich 2 Dokumente.

Comment: @puck: Wenn du deine Geburtsurkunde und deinen Meldezettel (also zwei Dokumente) einscannst und dabei ein zweiseitiges pdf-Dokument erhältst, dann ist das pdf-Dokument sehr wohl zwei Dokumente.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Um auf die Frage zurückzukommen, ich sage 1 kg sind 1000 g und 1000 g sind 1 kg. Deine Frage nach dem richtigen Verb würde ich mit "sind" beantworten. Für mich hört sich die Aussage "1 Gegenstand sind 2 Gegenstände" seltsam an weil ein Substantiv zweimal in verschiedener Anzahl verglichen wird. Wahrscheinlich ist das auch für dich der Grund um beides falsch zu finden. Das liegt aber nicht am Verb.

Comment: Zwei Paar != zwei Paare (man schreibt es nur gleich) - dieser Nachtrag hat aber nur am Rande mit der ursprünglich gestelletn Frage etwas zu tun. Was fehlt denn noch an tofros schöner Antwort? Ich bin mir zunehmend unsicher, was Du eigentlich von uns wissen möchtest.

Comment: @Takkat: Ich habe tofros Antwort bereits +1 gegeben. Ich hoffe aber noch auf eine zweite Meinung.

Comment: Natürlich kann man im Deutschen die Wortreihenfolge im Satz in Grenzen ändern und das natürlich auch in deinen Beispielsätzen tun. Ein Gleichstellungsnominativ verliert aber seinen Sinn, wenn man versucht, ein *generisches* Ding (mit unbestimmtem Artikel) und ein *spezifisches Ding* (mit bestimmtem Artikel gleichzusetzen. Es ist jedem  Muttersprachler klar, dass in einem Satz "Das A ist ein B" oder "Das A ist zwei Bs" A das Subjekt sein muß. "Ein Arzt ist mein Vater" stellt keinen semantisch sehr sinnvollen Satz dar, "Mein Vater ist Arzt" sehr wohl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ganz davon abgesehen, dass die Formulierung wirklich sehr unglücklich ist und sich wie schon erwähnt sehr nach dem alten Werbespruch "Ich bin zwei Öltanks" anhört:

Ganz nach den Regeln: *a ist ein b* bedeutet, dass a das Subjekt des Satzes ist und b das Subjektsprädikativ, und zwar vollkomen unabhängig davon,  ob es sich um einen Haupt- oder einen Nebensatz handelt - und da das Verb mit dem Subjekt kongruent sein muss, muss es wohl im Singular stehen, auch wenn *a zwei b* ist.

In den allermeisten solcher Zweifelsfälle steht laut Duden übrigens der Singular.

Hier liegt ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ vor, was zur Folge hat, dass nicht ganz klar sein kann, was tatsächlich das Subjekt ist. Einfaches Beispiel: Ich kann aus »Ein A ist ein B« durch vertauschen »Ein B ist ein A« machen. Das stimmt so im allgemeinen Fall, aber nicht in diesem - das spezifischere Substantiv wird automatisch als Subjekt, das unspezifischere als Subjektsprädikativ angenommen:

Aus

> Mein Vater ist der Arzt der englischen Königin

kann man problemlos durch Vertauschen von Subjekt und Subjektsprädikativ

> Der Arzt der englischen Königin ist mein Vater

machen (man beachte bestimmte und unbestimmte Artikel oder Nullartikel - Das ist das, was ich mit spezifisch und unspezifisch meine)

Aus

> Mein Vater ist Arzt

aber nicht ganz so problemlos

> Arzt ist mein Vater

machen (*Arzt* als Subjekt). Das funktioniert mit einem spezifischen Subjekt und einem unspezifischen Subjektsprädikativ zwar grammatisch (das ist immer noch ein grammatikalisch richtiger Satz), aber logisch nicht richtig. Man wird in beiden Formen "Mein Vater" als Subjekt betrachten). Dies gilt auch für dein Beispiel:

> **Das** Dokument ist eigentlich zwei Dokumente

Die Logik sagt, das Ding mit dem bestimmten Artikel muss das Subjekt sein und regiert deswegen das Verb.

Anderes Beispiel:

> Hans ist Maurer und Fliesenleger

ist sinnvoll und logisch richtig

> Maurer und Fliesenleger sind Hans

ist zwar grammatikalisch korrekt, ergibt aber keinen rechten Sinn.

Comment: Die Frage lautet eben genau nicht *»A ist **ein** B«*. Dabei gibt es ja keine Unklarheiten. Die erste Frage lautet: Was ist richtig: *»Das A ist zwei Bs«* oder *»Das A sind zwei Bs«*. Und die zweite Frage lautet: Was ist richtig: *»Es stimmt, dass das A zwei Bs ist«* oder *»Es stimmt, dass das A zwei Bs sind«*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In "A ist zwei Bs" ist A immer noch das Subjekt und regiert damit das Verb. Da ist kein Unterschied. Stell dir *Hans ist  Maurer und Fliesenleger" vor.

Comment: Hier liegt ein Gleichstellungsnominativ vor, was zur Folge hat, dass nicht ganz klar ist, was tatsächlich das Subjekt ist. Einfaches Beispiel: Ich kann aus »Ein A ist ein B« durch vertauschen »Ein B ist ein A machen« (so wie man auch aus »ich sehe dich« »dich sehe ich« machen kann). Nun gehe ich aber von »Ein A ist zwei Bs« aus. Durch Platztauschen wird daraus »Zwei Bs **ist** ein A«. Allerdings kann ich auch »zwei Bs« als Subjekt betrachten, dann muss es nach deinem Argument aber »Zwei Bs **sind** ein A« heißen. Wenn ich wieder zurücktausche wird daraus »Ein A **sind** zwei Bs«.

Comment: Der Gleichsetzungsnominativ (Das Subjektsprädikat) steht an Position 1, das Subjekt steht an Position 3, und dazwischen, auf Position 2 steht das Verb, das zum Subjekt kongruent ist, und daher im Plural stehen muss. Also »Ein A **sind** zwei Bs«. - Was spricht gegen diese Argumentation?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die Unterstellung, dass bei einem  Gleichstellungsnominativ Subjekt und Subjektprädikativ immer vertauschbar sei, gilt nicht mehr, wenn man von bestimmten und unbestimmten Dingen redet. "Mein Vater ist Arzt" ist nicht tauschbar. "Mein Vater ist der Arzt des Bundeskanzlers" schon. "Das Dokument ist zwei Dokumente" ist nicht tauschbar, "Das Dokument ist/sind die zwei Dokumente, die ich ihnen versprochen habe" schon. Dein Problem hättest du nur bei der zweiten Formulierung. So eine hast du aber nicht.

Comment: Ich präzisiere, bevor du insistierst: *Grammatisch richtige Sätze* sind natürlich auch "Arzt ist mein Vater" und "Zwei Dokumente sind das Dokument" - Das schließe ich nicht aus. Aber *sagen* wird das kein Mensch - normalerweise setzt man bei solchen Sätzen einfach aus Missverständlichkeitsgründen das bestimmte Subjekt an Position 1 und nimmt an dass das spezifischere Substantiv (das mit dem bestimmten Artikel) das Substantiv ist..